# How to copy a document on Alfresco via Alfresco Mobile SDK for Android?

Tags: android, copy, alfresco

I am trying to **copy a whole Folder**.

To do so I am creating a new folder and putting all again inside it : folders and documents.

But I am getting an Alfresco Service Exception when trying to create a Document:

> *Newly created object is not a document !*

My code is as below :

```
List<Document> documentsChildren = documentFolderService.getDocuments(folderToCopy);
for (Document document:documentsChildren){
ContentFile contentFileToCopy = documentFolderService.getContent(document);
String nameFileToCopy = document.getName();

// problem there
documentFolderService.createDocument(folderCopied, nameFileToCopy, properties, contentFileToCopy);
}
```

What is strange is that I yet implement the copy of a simple document inside a repository by the same way and it is working good:

```
Document documentToCopy = (Document) documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(fileToCopy.getIdentifier());
ContentFile contentFileToCopy = documentFolderService.getContent(documentToCopy);
String nameFileToCopy = fileToCopy.getName();
documentFolderService.createDocument(folderParent, nameFileToCopy, properties, contentFileToCopy);
```

The only thing that changes is the way to obtain the document : by taking the children documents of a folder or by getting the document with his identifier.

### Update of the question :

The exact message of error is:

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.exceptions.AlfrescoServiceException: Newly created object is not a document! New id: workspace://SpacesStore/85753128-1ac9-4b5e-b909-91dcb7d5ff5d
at org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.services.impl.AbstractDocumentFolderServiceImpl.createDocument(AbstractDocumentFolderServiceImpl.java:482)
```

- properties is en empty map :

  Map properties = new HashMap();
- I test for .ppt documents, and as you ask the question, I also test for .docx and .jpg
- the type of the node when the exception is raised is a folder

The quick fix that you proposed is not working.
Maybe I am doing a stupid error somewhere but I don't manage to find it.

### Complete code :

```
List<Folder> foldersChildren = null;
List<Document> documentsChildren = null;
try {
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = Login.session.getServiceRegistry();
        DocumentFolderService documentFolderService = serviceRegistry.getDocumentFolderService();
        Folder folderParent = (Folder) documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(repositoryParent.getIdentifier());

        // create the folder
        Map<String,Serializable> properties = new HashMap<String,Serializable>();   
        Folder folderToCopy = (Folder) documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(repositoryToCopy.getIdentifier());
        String nameRepositoryToCopy = repositoryToCopy.getName();
        Folder folderCopied = documentFolderService.createFolder(folderParent, nameRepositoryToCopy, properties);

        foldersChildren = documentFolderService.getFolders(folderToCopy);
        documentsChildren = documentFolderService.getDocuments(folderToCopy);

        // create the files inside the folder
        ContentFile contentFileToCopy = null;
        String nameFileToCopy = null;
        for (Document document : documentsChildren){
            contentFileToCopy = documentFolderService.getContent(document);
            nameFileToCopy = document.getName();

            // this operation doesn't work
            documentFolderService.createDocument(folderCopied, nameFileToCopy, properties, contentFileToCopy);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        this.cancel(true);
        UIAlertDialog.runOnUIThreadOperationFailed(activity, context);
    }
```

Comment: Are you only copying documents, or are you copying folders too? Only a call to createDocument won't be allowed if you're trying to copy a folder node

Comment: Yes I am copying folders too, but I want to keep the hierarchy, so I create a new folder, and I create new folders and new documents inside this first folder.
To create a folder I use another method:
Folder folderCopied = documentFolderService.createFolder(folderParent, nameRepositoryToCopy, properties);

Comment: You said in your question *the type of the node when the exception is raised is a folder* - you can't create a folder with createDocument!

Comment: Ok true, I didn't explained well. The list of documents it is well a list of documents (and not folders), you can't get the ContentFile from a folder, so it is well a document at this level alos, but when I call the createDocument function, it raised me an error that I don't manage to understand as it is a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message explained : ***Newly created object is not a document*** ! 
this error happens after the creation of the document when the method check if the current node is correctly created and have the right attributes.

I need more informations (stacktrace, type of the node...) to know if it's a bug on SDK side or a specific the method doesn't cover. 
Could you provide informations

- properties value : Is it an empty map ? the same map as the copied one ?
- Does it happen for every document or just for some types of document ?
- What's the type of the node when the exception is raised ?

But if the second method work, a quick fix could be :

```
List<Document> documentsChildren = documentFolderService.getDocuments(folderToCopy);
Document documentToCopy = null;
ContentFile contentFileToCopy = null;
String nameFileToCopy = null;
for (Document document : documentsChildren){
   documentToCopy = (Document) documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(document .getIdentifier());
   contentFileToCopy = documentFolderService.getContent(documentToCopy);
   nameFileToCopy = fileToCopy.getName();
   documentFolderService.createDocument(folderParent, nameFileToCopy, properties, contentFileToCopy);
}
```

**EDIT 06.02**

Apparently there's an issue reference with the properties object inside  documentFolderService.createFolder(). The map is not empty after this method and contains informations that disturb the next part of your code.
So to correct it (and if for you properties are not important during copy operation), please find the solution

```
List<Folder> foldersChildren = null; 
List<Document> documentsChildren = null; 
try {
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = Login.session.getServiceRegistry();
        DocumentFolderService documentFolderService = serviceRegistry.getDocumentFolderService();
        Folder folderParent = (Folder) documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(repositoryParent.getIdentifier());

        // create the folder
        Folder folderToCopy = (Folder) documentFolderService.getNodeByIdentifier(repositoryToCopy.getIdentifier());
        String nameRepositoryToCopy = repositoryToCopy.getName();
        Folder folderCopied = documentFolderService.createFolder(folderParent, nameRepositoryToCopy, null);

        foldersChildren = documentFolderService.getFolders(folderToCopy);
        documentsChildren = documentFolderService.getDocuments(folderToCopy);

        // create the files inside the folder
        ContentFile contentFileToCopy = null;
        String nameFileToCopy = null;
        for (Document document : documentsChildren){
            contentFileToCopy = documentFolderService.getContent(document);
            nameFileToCopy = document.getName();

            // this operation doesn't work
            documentFolderService.createDocument(folderCopied, nameFileToCopy, null, contentFileToCopy);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        this.cancel(true);
        UIAlertDialog.runOnUIThreadOperationFailed(activity, context);
    }
```

NB : Properties is an optional parameter so it can be null.

Comment: I had updated my question to give you the information that you need. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Thanks this is the irght solution !